# SQL: Insert certain records from one table into another and also add few other fields using query

Tags: sql, apache-drill

I have two tables say TABLE1 and TABLE2. And say the field `id` is common in both. Rest of field are different.

I now select all distinct `id` from TABLE1 and want to insert them into TABLE2 while also writing its other attributes. Like the pseudocode below.

```
for each distinct id (i) in TABLE1:
    INSERT in TABLE2 (i, false, unix_timestamp())
end
```

Now I for some reason cannot use a programming language to do this. Is it possible to do this in SQL using Apache Drill?

Comment: Tables have _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is write a query that produces the output you're looking for and then save that as a table.  Drill is really a query engine and doesn't support `INSERT` operations the way a database does.

So a pseudo query migth look like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE <your file> AS
SELECT ...
```

Then you could query that file.  I don't know if that helps or not.  You can also create views and temporary tables, but Drill itself doesn't really implement `INSERT` commands.